# javaで西暦→和暦変換がうまくいかない

Tags: java

画面入力値の西暦を、和暦に変換する必要があり、質問します。
以下スースの通り作成したのですが、入力値の「月」が+1されてしまいます。
解決法を教えてください。

入力値（以下ソースのcalender.set(2016, 3, 24);部分）　→　2016, 3, 24
実行結果　→　平成28年4月30日

となり3月となってほしいのに4月となってしまいます。

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP");
    DateFormat japaneseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("GGGGy年M月d日",
            defaultLocale);

    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(2016, 3, 24);

    System.out.println(japaneseFormat.format(calender.getTime()));
  }
}
```

ポイントは、システム日付ではなく、外部から与えられた引数で西暦→和暦に変換したいです。

Answer (score 7):

Javadocにもひっそり書いてあるのですが、月は0始まりのためですね。

[Calendar#set(int, int, int) (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-)

> month - MONTH カレンダフィールドの設定に使用する値。Month 値は 0 から始まる (1 月は 0 になる)。

3月にするためには、

```
    calender.set(2016, 2, 24);
```

とする必要があります。

Answer (score 6):

JDK8以降であれば、java.time.chrono.JapaneseDateを使って和暦を取得することもできます。こちらはそのままの月を設定できる感じです。
[java.time.chrono.JapaneseDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/JapaneseDate.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Gyy年M月d日");
JapaneseDate japaneseDate = JapaneseDate.of(2016, 3, 24);
System.out.println(japaneseDate.format(formatter));
// 平成28年3月24日
```